# Swap columns with a condition in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two columns- `x` and `y`. `x` should be always less than `y` in my output table.

How to swap? I tried update which didn't work and throws runtime error. Can someone give the correct syntax ?

```sql
Update table t1 set x = (case when x<y then x else y end),
                set y = (case when x<y then y else x end)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use a `WHERE` clause to update only the rows that actually need to be updated:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET x = y,
    y = x
WHERE x > y;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. There should be no 'TABLE' in the `UPDATE`  statement.
You have `SET` twice, it's only wanted once

```
Update t1 set x = (case when x<y then x else y end),
 y = (case when x<y then y else x end)
```